# Webpack weirdly export two images in dist

Tags: webpack

As in title, after build, I found 2 images in dist folder

- one with hashed name(the broken one) and
- one with original name(the good one)

but my index.html(in dist) is referenced to the broken one

---

After few hours of trying, I fixed this problem by commenting out this part in config

```
{
    test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|webp)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
      }
    }
  }
```

It's super weird for me because I thought I need file-loader to handle those pictures

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BtXu.png)

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "js", "index.js"),
    // main: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "js", "main.js"),
  },
  output: {
    filename:'[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist") //output to ./build
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader}, "css-loader",'postcss-loader',"sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|[ot]tf)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: './fonts/',
              publicPath: '/fonts/'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
          }
        },
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|webp)$/,
      //   use: {
      //     loader: 'file-loader',
      //   }
      // }
      
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: './[name].css',})
  ],

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
              output: {
                  comments: false
              }
          },
          extractComments: false
      })
    ]
  }

};
```

Comment: Can you list all your config and package.json

Comment: Do you have htmlwebpackplugin and html-loader config

Comment: Yes, I have both!
I have update my question, thank you for your reply!

Comment: hey I'm really late to this question but I was having the EXACT same issue as you. commenting out the same code fixed it for me too!. However, did you ever figure out why exactly it worked? I'm also very very confused

Comment: I guess in Webpack 5 we don't need file loader anymore.
https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/
A little line on the top: Deprecated for v5